# Evaluate JS/TS code in the context of VS Code like elisp in emacs

Tags: visual-studio-code, emacs

I am a long time emacs user. What I love about it is neither the keybindings nor emacs lisp but rather the fact that I can write ad hoc code to do everyday things like manipulate buffers, the cursor, make quick ad-hoc modes that highlight different things, etc. I also like that emacs is configured by executable rc files rather than a json config files. I could probably live without all the other features I like (eg. org-mode, comint mode, compilation mode, even keyboard macros if I have to)

I have decided to give VS Code a try and I was wondering how close I can get to the state of affairs I described about emacs. As far as I understand VS Code is operates on a javascript(/typescript) VM. Is there an "evaluate expression" family of features (like `eval-expression`/`eval-defun`/etc).

Answer (score 1):

There's the [`iocave.monkey-patch`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch) extension <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>, which "*allowing execution of arbitrary javascript in VSCode browser and main process*".

There might be limitations like mentioned in [Monkey path not loading in VSCode 1.74.0 #55](https://github.com/iocave/monkey-patch/issues/55) due to [TS - mangle private and protected props #166126](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/166126) (related discussion in [Engineering: private and protected properties are being mangled now #257](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/257)). See also [Annoucement: Customize UI is probably not going to work anymore
#156](https://github.com/iocave/customize-ui/issues/156).